# extract a quoted value from multiple lines using sed

Tags: bash, command-line, sed, awk, grep

I'm a total n00b when it comes to using `sed` and can't quite figure this out...

I've got the following data being output by a command line tool:

```
ruby:
interpreter:  "ruby"
version:      "1.8.6"
date:         "2010-02-04"
platform:     "i386-mingw32"
patchlevel:   "398"
full_version: "ruby 1.8.6 (2010-02-04 patchlevel 398) [i386-mingw32]"

homes:
gem:          ""
ruby:         "C:\ruby\ruby-1.8.6-p398-i386-mingw32"

binaries:
ruby:         "C:\ruby\ruby-1.8.6-p398-i386-mingw32\bin"
irb:          "C:\ruby\ruby-1.8.6-p398-i386-mingw32\bin\irb.bat"
gem:          "C:\ruby\ruby-1.8.6-p398-i386-mingw32\bin\gem.bat"
rake:         ""

environment:
GEM_HOME:     ""
HOME:         "c:/Users/derick"
IRBRC:        ""
RUBYOPT:      ""

file associations:
.rb:
.rbw:
```

I want to use sed to extract the values from `interpreter` and `version` only, and have them returned as "interpreter-version".

The best I could come up with so far is to use grep to return the entire version line:

`pik info | grep -e '^version:.*'`

but that returns too much info from the version line, and doesn't include the interpreter (obviously).

How can i use `sed` to extract only the bits of information that i want, so that i get a result of `ruby-1.8.6`?

... or grep, or awk, or any other command line tool to get the info i want...

FWIW: i'm not using RVM because this is a windows machine using MinGW32... i'm using Pik, which is similar to RVM but made for windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would working with the 'full_version' string be useful?

```
pik info | awk '/full_version/ {print $2,$3}' | sed 's/\"//;s/\s/\-/'
```

I'm certain the sed bit could be folded into the awk bit with 'sub()', but I'll leave it to someone more versed in awk.

Comment: OK, `awk -F '"' '/^full_version:/ {split($2,a," "); print a[1] "-" a[2]; exit}'`

Answer (score 4):

A lot of you are working hard to deal with the quotes.  Let awk do it:

```
pik info | awk -F '"' '
    /^interpreter:/ {interp = $2} 
    /^version:/     {ver = $2}
    interp && ver   {print interp "-" ver; exit}
'
```

Answer (score 3):

It is easy enough to do in pure 'sed' if you're aware of the 'hold space':

```
sed -n '/^interpreter: *"\(.*\)"/{
s//\1/
h
}
/^version: *"\(.*\)"/{
s// \1/
H
x
s/\n//
s/.*/interpreter-version: "&"/p
}'
```

The script overall doesn't print anything (`-n`) unless you command it to.  The first pattern searched for is the interpreter line; we capture the name of the interpreter, then remove all the rest of the material, and copy the interpretr name (plus a newline) into the hold space ('`h`').  The second pattern searched for is the version string.  We similarly isolate just the version number - prefixing it with a space.  Then we concatenate the version number to the hold space ('`H`'), and swap the hold and pattern spaces ('`x`').  We remove the newline in between the interpreter name and the version number; then prefix it with '`interpreter-version: "`' and follow it with a closing double quote and print the result:

```
interpreter-version: "ruby 1.8.6"
```

And if what you really want is 'ruby-1.8.6', then the changes are minor:

```
sed -n '/^interpreter: *"\(.*\)"/{
s//\1/
h
}
/^version: *"\(.*\)"/{
s//-\1/
H
x
s/\n//p
}'
```

This prefixes the version with a dash instead of a space, and then only has to remove the newline before printing after exchanging the hold and pattern spaces.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I vote this up because I nothing but respect for people who know sed/awk like you do, however, is `sed` really a suitable tool here? I mean, yes, you can use the hold space to store information but is not `awk` better suited here?

Comment: @Anders: I addressed the subject line - which says 'sed' - though the body does acknowledge grep (not really suitable) or awk as alternatives. In some ways, awk is better, but it is messy eliminating the double quote - witness your answer which pipes the output of awk through sed. In the circumstances, I'd probably use Perl (or, if I were more fluent in it, Python); those can deal with the lot very easily. So, if the job were much more complex (required saving two bits of data instead of just one, for example), then 'sed' would not be appropriate. It is border-line for this job - works, but...

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, There is no need to defend your choice! I was merely curious to why you choose to use only sed, thats it. Being forced to work on old Solaris machines has given me a new level of respect for people who, like you, have good knowledge in sed/awk!

Comment: @Anders: I learned sed and (old) awk before there was 'perl' :( I still have a scary script, used regularly but last modified in 1998, that runs 4 sed scripts in a row, three of them complicated enough to be scripted into a file, and two of them marked 'entertaining'; one of them generates shell script. One reason it hasn't been changed is that I'm not sure, despite the documentation, that I understand exactly what they're up to. Fortunately, I've not changed the requirements on the script since 1998, either.  But it is scary having 'unmodifiable' code. I'm sure if I put my mind to it...but...

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, Hehe, I remember complaining at work being forced to use simply awk/sed to generate JSON from an applications output. Guess one needs to put everything in perspective :-)

Comment: My take on sed vs awk is that Real Programmers use sed. I mean, come on, awk is halfway to perl, and that's halfway to LISP! Just to pull a couple of strings out of a stream!

Comment: @Tom Anderson, That seems to be the case with the senior staff where I work also, they use `sed` for mostly everything. I don't think I have ever seen them use `awk`. I like to think I select the tool based on the job, but in all honestly it's probably because I have limited knowledge working with both `sed`/`awk`, alone, but combining them with my knowledge is often enough.

Answer (score 2):

1) capture to file what's being output by your command line tool i.e. something >> outfile
2) on my bash/ubuntu box"

```
grep -e "interpreter" -e "version" outfile | awk 'BEGIN {print"Interpreter-Version" }{print $2}'| sed 's/"//g'| tr '\n' ' '
```

3) The output:

```
Interpreter-Version ruby 1.8.6
```

I am sure it could be optimized but it worked for me :-)

HTH,

Chris.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
pik info | awk '/^interpreter:/ {inter=$2; gsub(/"/, "", inter)} /^version:/ {vers=$2; gsub(/"/, "", vers)} END {print inter "-" vers}'
```

generates ...

```
ruby-1.8.6
```

Answer (score 1):

A version using both `awk` and `sed`.

```
pik info | awk '/^interpreter:|^version:/ {printf "%s-", $2}' | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/-$//'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only `sed`:

```
pik info | sed -n '/^full_version: "\([^(]*\)(.*/ {s//\1/; s/ /-/;p}'
```